# How to restore operating system on iMac (Late 2006)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac

I got a keyboard for it, but it's not paired and apparently won't because there is no version of OS X found.

[image]

I have the DVD containing OS X but can't eject a disc already in it because of the keyboard issue.

Comment: I think the simplest answer is to grab a keyboard that doesn't require BT (USB) and connect it for now while you reload the operating system.

Comment: Try force eject disk methods, found on google.com